# Editing a Sharepoint 2010 List record with Access 2013 - "Cannot Update. Database or object is read-only"

Tags: permissions, microsoft-access, read-only

I've got kind of a weird problem, and I haven't been able to find an answer.  I'm accessing a sharepoint list through Access, and I'd like to change a "status" field from "pending" to "complete".  When I try to make that change, I get a popup that says "Cannot Update.  Database or object is read-only."  I've given myself contribute rights to the sharepoint list in question, and though I can add to the list, I cannot modify what already exists.  No formulae are being applied to the field I'm trying to edit, either.  Does anybody have recommendations on how to diagnose and root out this problem?  
  Thank you!
Kindly,
Peter

Comment: Do you have any required field that are not filled ? Do you use multiple  content type in your list ?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  To answer:  Every required field is filled, and the field in question is a required one.  As for the "Multiple Content Types", the list is set to "Allow the management of content types", but I didn't see a specific box for allowing multiple content types.  I feel like this, (the advanced settings section for the list), is the typical spot where that option would display, but I'm not seeing it...

Comment: I had a similar issue with Datasheet view. Try disabling the "allow management of content types", put all the list column optional, then put back the management of content types and set the required field via the content type.

Comment: Awesome!  I'll give this a shot.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get this to work.  For confirmation:  I gave the following a shot:  I turned off the "allow mgmt of content types", turned off any required fields, then turned "mgmt of content" back on, and set the needed fields as required under the "Content Type" heading.  Are there any other recommendations you'd suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow-up answer:  The trouble is that I was trying to unit-test my updates within the Datasheet view of my employee table.  When I implemented a change directly through a query, I had no troubles.  Thanks to JayHell for providing the context that allowed me to deduce this.